# Coverage done by monitor or subscriber in UVM

Tags: uvm

Is the coverage check done in monitor or in the subscriber in UVM? I get two different views. In the Cluelogic link, it says that coverage check is done in subscriber, but in the UVM accelera user guide, it mentions that overage check is done inside monitor (page 49, Section 3.6). Can someone please clarify.

http://cluelogic.com/2011/07/uvm-tutorial-for-candy-lovers-environment/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can sample your coverage data anywhere in your verification environment, including `uvm_monitor` or `uvm_subscriber`.

However, generally coverage is being sampled in `uvm_subscriber` and the reason is that, different designs may require different type of coverage bins and hence it is easy to plug that component and make your core code independent of the coverage.

So generally an analysis port from `uvm_monitor` is provided at the upper levels, and if someone wants to implement his/her own coverage, then he/she can simply connect `analysis_export` of the `uvm_subscriber` to the analysis port of the monitor and sample the coverage in the `write` method.